# Is there a term for when an illness itself prevents the patient from obtaining a cure?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A challenge to curing patients is that sometimes the illness itself prevents a patient from taking a cure.

Some examples:

- Depression - lack of motivation and negative thinking prevent the patient from seeking help or carrying out their treatment.
- Dementia - the patient may forget to carry out their treatment.
- Anorexia/Paranoid Schizophrenia - part of the illness includes the belief that they are not ill and possibly even that doctors are working against them.
- Any illness where the patient is too physically incapacitated to contact a doctor or carry out their treatment.

Is there a term for this problem?

Comment: It's kind of like a negative feedback loop, but I don't think that term is typically used for it.

Comment: A curing patient is being roasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps they are ***trapped in a cycle of decline***.

But provided their condition is curable it is the job of a good doctor to get them out of it.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>I'm not sure how well this fits your context of patients and treatments, but consider:</sub>

**Vicious circle** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vicious+circle)

> 1. A situation in which the apparent solution of one problem in a chain of circumstances creates a new problem and increases the difficulty of solving the original problem.
> 2. **A condition in which a disorder or disease gives rise to another that subsequently affects the first.**

**Vicious cycle** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vicious+cycle)

> one trouble leads to another that aggravates the first

**Self-fulfilling prophecy** — [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/self-fulfilling-prophecy.html)

> Any positive or negative expectation about circumstances, events, or people that may affect a person's behavior toward them in a manner that causes those expectations to be fulfilled.
>
> An employer who, for example, expects the employees to be disloyal and shirkers, will likely treat them in a way that will elicit the very response he or she expects.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest [**self-perpetuating**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/self-perpetuating).

> having a ​system that ​prevents ​change and ​produces new things that are very ​similar to the ​old ​ones